# Are there non-aesthetic differences to consider between hinting techniques when writing in CFScript?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, code-hinting

I'm aware of two methods to write code hints in CFScript. I would like to know if there are any functional, non-aesthetic differences between the two, and what's considered best practice.

The first technique I've seen uses comments above the function's declaration to add hints:

```
/**
* @hint This function does soemthing
*/
public function foo() {}
```

While the second technique incorporates the hints into the declaration itself:

```
public function foo() hint="This function does something" {}
```

Are there reasons to use one and not the other? Does your approach change if you have arguments to declare that you may want to hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference that I am aware of between using the annotation style /** */ and inline.  Also, it's not just hints - any attributes can be placed in the annotation or inline.  As far as I am aware it's purely an aesthetic choice.

To clarify:

```
/**
*@output false
*@returnType query
*/
public function foo() {}
```

Will functionally do the same exact thing as

```
public function foo() output='false' returntype='query' {}
```

Comment: Todd, this is interesting... I thought "public" being the first word of the function declared the "access='public'" -- what's the use of including it in the annotation?

Comment: Ah yes - sorry - that's not necessary.  Was just looking at a tag based CFC in my IDE as an example and didn't pay much attention.  I'll remove it from the annotation for clarity.

Comment: "query" return type should be between to public and function keyword, no need to use returntype=

Comment: Works either way, but yes, that is a shortcut Henry. My point was simply that attributes can be inline or annotation style.

Comment: If we're getting technical I didn't even have to say output='false' because that is implied in cfscript based functions.

Answer (score 6):

The first style, JavaDoc style, is a little cleaner looking, but I have a huge personal gripe against it:

**Comments should never alter the way that code runs. EVER. That's why they are called comments!**

That is why I prefer the second style, even though it is not as clean looking.

Comment: I think you're being a bit dramatic with your font size there, but to each his own ;)

Comment: It's something I'm passionate about. Comments modifying code execution is fundamentally evil.

Comment: Maybe it was a bit over the top. Changed it. :P

Comment: To be fair - it's not a comment, it's an annotation. :)

Comment: @Adam, I agree with you. I think it is a bit weird to think that comments can modify code execution...

Comment: @Todd: Sure, it's an annotation. Explain that to the new guy who is wondering why his method is remote-accessible when he doesn't want it to be, and he just hasn't noticed that @access remote is in the comments.

Comment: +1 Adam, I agree completely. Allowing program functionality inside comments was a terrible architectural decision. I could understand basing an automatic *documentation* feature on JavaDoc. That would make sense. But the decision to do it this way has created an ambiguous weak point in the language, and a likely WTF moment for newcomers to the cfml/cfscript world.

Answer (score 1):

Using `getComponentMetaData()` attributes take precedence over comments. Otherwise there's no technical difference. The [Adobe documentation on cfscript components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSE99A664D-44E3-44d1-92A0-5FDF8D82B55C.html) is actually pretty good on this topic.

I think using comments is a better approach to communicate intent to readers because it stands apart from the code that it precedes. Whereas attributes are better used to apply customization (e.g. hinting for an ORM) because it places that information inline with other code.